# Can adapters convert between different thread sizes for reverse mounting a lens?

Tags: macro, reverse-mount, filter-diameter

Can adapters be used to convert between different lens filter thread sizes when used to reverse mount a lens for macro, and is there any disadvantage in doing so?

<sub>Split from this question: [Does the lens mount matter when reverse mounting for macro?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18759/does-the-lens-mount-matter-when-reverse-mounting-for-macro)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a '49mm-52mm Step-Up Ring' and a '52mm Macro Reverse Adapter Ring for Pentax K'  to reverse mount my [SMC PENTAX-A 1:2 50mm](http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/lenses/primes/normal/A50f2.html) lens which has a 49mm filter thread. It's working great and I don't see any disadvantage. Of course it would be cheaper and simpler to use a '49mm Macro Reverse Adapter' but I was unable to find one in the local store (many years ago).